# enable depth regristration by default (openni_launch)

Tags: openni-launch, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm a new ROS-User and I want to modify the openni_launch file so that it enables the depth-regristration by default. Normaly I have to use the dynamic_reconfigure gui to set that parameter.
Now the problem is that I dont know how the parameter is exactly called and with node it is. Do I have to set it for the openni_launch node or the dynamic reconfigure node? I read throught the wiki page http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML but that did helped me much because I still not know if I need to set the parameter to a specific node or is a general variable on the parameter server.

would be great to get some help.
regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12519/enable-depth-regristration-by-default-(openni_launch)/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This Question has been already answered here: [Activating OpenNi depth registration by default](http://answers.ros.org/question/2905/activating-openni-depth-registration-by-default)

You can edit your launch files to automatically enable depth registration.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2